# Tic tac toe resets every other turn

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm in the middle of trying to make a tic tac toe board and this is what I have so far. Unfortunately, after each player 2's turn, the board resets and I can't figure out what I need to do the fix it.

```
def display_board(board):
    print(board[7]+' |'+board[8]+' |'+board[9])
    print('-----')
    print(board[4]+' |'+board[5]+' |'+board[6])
    print('-----')
    print(board[1]+' |'+board[2]+' |'+board[3])

def player_input():
    marker = ''
    while marker == '':
        answer = input("Player 1, please choose X or O. ")
        if answer == 'O' or answer == 'X':
            marker = answer
        else:
            print("Answer was not X or O")
    while marker == 'X':
        gameplay('X','O')
    while marker == 'O':
        gameplay('O','X')
        
def gameplay(player1,player2):
    spaces = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    board = ['#','','','','','','','','','']
    turn = True
    while turn is True:
        display_board(board)
        position = input("Player 1 pick a position(1-9)")
        if position not in spaces:
           print("Please pick a number 1-9")
        elif board[int(position)] == '' and position in spaces:
            board[int(position)] = player1
            turn = False
        else:
            print("Space already taken. Choose different position.")

    while turn is False:
        display_board(board)
        position2 = input("Player 2 pick a position(1-9)")
        if position not in spaces:
           print("Please pick a number 1-9")
        elif board[int(position2)] == '' and position2 in spaces:
            board[int(position2)] = player2
            turn = True
        else:
            print("Space already taken. Choose different position.")
```

Comment: Every time you run the `gameplay` function, you're resetting your board to default.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have another `while` loop that controls the game

```
    while not board_is_full:
        while turn: # turn of player 1
            display_board(board)
            position = input("Player 1 pick a position(1-9)")
            if position not in spaces:
               print("Please pick a number 1-9")
            elif board[int(position)] == '' and position in spaces:
                board[int(position)] = player1
                turn = False
            else:
                print("Space already taken. Choose different position.")
        while not turn: # turn of player 2
            display_board(board)
            position2 = input("Player 2 pick a position(1-9)")
            if position not in spaces:
               print("Please pick a number 1-9")
            elif board[int(position2)] == '' and position2 in spaces:
                board[int(position2)] = player2
                turn = True
            else:
                print("Space already taken. Choose different position.")
```

You should have one loop that ends only when board is full. To check it you can e.g. count moves, or check every position of your board.

As a bonus, notice your functions looks almost identical! You could separate it into another one.

```
def player_move(player, player_number):
    display_board(board)
    position = input(f"Player {player_number} pick a position(1-9)")
    if position not in spaces:
       print("Please pick a number 1-9")
       # we can run it recursively until correct number is provided
       player_move(player, player_number)
    elif board[int(position)] == '' and position in spaces:
        board[int(position)] = player
    else:
        print("Space already taken. Choose different position.")
        player_move(player, player_number)

...

   while not board_is_full:
       player_move(player1, 1)
       player_move(player2, 2)
```